# nth fibonacci number using using dynamic programming

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

I am able to understand the dynamic programming implementation given [HERE](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/).

But I am not clear about the another version given in cracking the coding interview book which I am copy pasting. Can someone please help me understand this, moreover is this not more expensive than the above geeksforgeek dynamic programming implementation.

```
int[] fib = new int[max];
int fibonacci(int i){
if(i == 0) return 0;
if(i == 1) return 1;
if (fib[i] != 0) return fid[i];
fib[i] = fibonacci(i-1) + fibonacci(i-2);
return fib[i];
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to run this in a debugger to see how the method behaves. After that it should be clear how dynamic programming works for computing the nth fibonacci number.

Comment: `Line 5, column 25: identifier 'fid' not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `int[] fib` is a cache in which the `i`th fibonacci number is stored.

This is a great time saver. Otherwise the recursive fibonacci procedure would need to recalculate a lot of values.

E.g.

```
fib[8] = fibonacci(7) + fibonacci(6)
```

But then:

```
fib[7] = fibonacci(6) + fibonacci(5)
```

As you can see, without caching, the value for `fibonacci(6)` would be needed to calculated two times.